# Call break in nested if statements

Tags: javascript

I have the following situation:

```
IF condition THEN  
    IF condition THEN 
        sequence 1
    ELSE
        break //?  
    ENDIF    
ELSE    
    sequence 3    
ENDIF
```

What is the result of the break statement? Does it break the outer if statement? Because this is what I actually need.

Comment: The `break` keyword doesn't work with `if` statements, does it?

Comment: @Marcelo: jep, else you couldn't do something like `while(true){ if(condition) {break;}}`...

Comment: That wasn’t a joke: JavaScript does support jumping to a particular [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) using `break`: `break <label>; <label>: <code>`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

no it doesnt.  break is for loops, not ifs.

nested if statements are just terrible.  If you can avoid them, avoid them.   Can you rewrite your code to be something like

```
if (c1 && c2) {
    //sequence 1
} else if (c3 && c2) {
   // sequence 3
}
```

that way you don't need any control logic to 'break out' of the loop.

Answer (score 224):

If you label the if statement you can use break.

```
breakme: if (condition) {
    // Do stuff

    if (condition2){
        // do stuff
    } else {
       break breakme;
    }

    // Do more stuff
}
```

You can even label and break plain blocks.

```
breakme: {
    // Do stuff

    if (condition){
        // do stuff
    } else {
       break breakme;
    }

    // Do more stuff
}
```

It's not a commonly used pattern though, so might confuse people and possibly won't be optimised by compliers.  It might be better to use a function and return, or better arrange the conditions.

```
( function() {
   // Do stuff

   if ( condition1 ) {
       // Do stuff 
   } else {
       return;
   }

   // Do other stuff
}() );
```

Comment: I was getting the headaches because none of your two examples of labeling was working for me (I never used labels before). I was suspecting on the `break breakme:` line and... voilà! It was due the final colon. There should be a semicolon instead (or even anything).

Comment: My use case for this was to have a finally type block at the end of an if else chain. The problem I had was that if something was null half way through the body of a given if then I had to stop, but I still needed to execute the last bit of code. My first thought was to just turn each body into an iife and use return, but the label and break seems like a more sensible choice in this situation.

Comment: Amazing that you just taught me something so fundamental, for a language I've been paid to write in for almost two years.

Comment: Javascript never fails to amaze us.

Answer (score 4):

But there is switch-case :)

```
switch (true) {
    case true:
        console.log("Yes, its ture :) Break from the switch-case");
        break;
    case false:
        console.log("Nope, but if the condition was set to false this would be used and then break");
        break;

    default:
        console.log("If all else fails");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the most languages, break does only cancel loops like for, while etc.

Answer (score 3):

To make multiple checking statements more readable (and avoid nested ifs):

```
var tmp = 'Test[some.email@somewhereouttherebutnothere.com]';

var posStartEmail = undefined;
var posEndEmail = undefined;
var email = undefined;

do {
    if (tmp.toLowerCase().substring(0,4) !== 'test') { break; }

    posStartEmail = tmp.toLowerCase().substring(4).indexOf('[');
    posEndEmail = tmp.toLowerCase().substring(4).indexOf(']');

    if (posStartEmail === -1 || posEndEmail === -1) { break; }

    email = tmp.substring(posStartEmail+1+4,posEndEmail);

    if (email.indexOf('@') === -1) { break; }

// all checks are done - do what you intend to do

    alert ('All checks are ok')

    break; // the most important break of them all

} while(true);
```

Comment: Why not `} while (false)`? That would make the most important break unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will throw an exception if you attempt to use a `break;` statement inside an if else.  It is used mainly for loops.  You can "break" out of an if else statement with a condition, which does not make sense to include a "break" statement.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/HjtGB/)

Comment: that's only correct if there's no outer loop, break; can be inside an if or else, if it's inside a for or while.

Comment: yes that is correct.  answer is based off example supplied by the poster with a set lines of codes.  poster did not mention if else statement wrapped by a for or a while. @Benja

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no c3 in the sample code in the original question.  So the if would be more properly

```
if (c1 && c2) {
    //sequence 1
} else if (!c1 && !c2) {
   // sequence 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today and found refactoring the conditional logic into a separate function to help.

I find it more readable than the labels and people are more comfortable with `return` than `break`. Inline functions are similar but the indentation can get a bit confusing.

In your case it would look like this.

```
function doThing() {
  checkConditions();

  // Rest of the code here
}

function checkConditions() {
  if (c1) {
    if (c2) {
      return do1();
    else {
      return;
    }
  } else {
    return do3();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way too:

```
for (let _ of [1])
if (some-condition){
    // do something

    // need to break?
    if (need to break) break;

    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For whom it might concern, it is currently possible to break out from `if` conditions like so:

```
let a = 0
initialCondition: if (a === 0) {
    console.log('first', a)
  a++;
    console.log('second', a)
  a++;
    console.log('third', a)
  
  if (a <= 2) {
    break initialCondition;
  }
  
  a++;
  
  console.log("fourth", a)
}
```

In the snippet above, the last `console.log` statement is not excecuted.
Feel free to tweak with it at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wq3rojc6/)

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the break. since it is already inside first if it will not execute else. It will exit anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You need that it breaks the outer if statement. Why do you use second else?

```
IF condition THEN  
    IF condition THEN 
        sequence 1
    // ELSE sequence 4
       // break //?  
    // ENDIF    
ELSE    
    sequence 3    
ENDIF

sequence 4
```