# Getting illegal Usage of Break in the for loop nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a for loop, but when I execute its throwing error. Below is the for loop

```
 for (let minusDate = 0; minusDate < 8; minusDate++) {
        buildCheckDate = `${year}-${month}-${tdate-minusDate}`;
        let params = {
            Bucket : "sample",
            Key: `sample/${buildCheckDate}/file.txt`,
          };
        s3.headObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (data) {
                break;
                console.log(`file exists in ${buildCheckDate}`); 
            } else {
                continue;
                console.log(`file not exists in ${buildCheckDate}`); 
            }
        });
```

I get below error `SyntaxError: Illegal break statement` Please help to point out where i am wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call break in nested if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851657/call-break-in-nested-if-statements)

Comment: nope @Roy I think my break statement comes inside the function. But how can i change that?

Answer (score 1):

what I would suggest you to do is the following

```
    for (let minusDate = 0; minusDate < 8; minusDate++) {
        buildCheckDate = `${year}-${month}-${tdate - minusDate}`;
        let params = {
            Bucket: "sample",
            Key: `sample/${buildCheckDate}/file.txt`,
        };
        const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            s3.headObject(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(data);
            });
        });

        if (!!data) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Basically you are wrapping the s3 method using a callback into a promise.

Which allow you to wait for the data (or not) and depending on the result, you can do whatever you need.

Of course, to be able to use await your function around must be async and awaited by the consumer.

Comment: got an error - SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: please help, I am new to nodejs

Comment: Your method around must be async

Comment: Is that alright ??

Comment: yes, could you please write in async

Comment: Got an error -  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NotFound: null

Comment: I do not know the context in which you run that loop, wrapping the loop in the async function Is just an example. Could you provide the context around

Answer (score -1):

The `break` (and `continue`) statements are occurring in the callback function body without any enclosing `for` loop around. You should return appropriate values instead and check for those values in the `for` loop.